# I want show date and time on label in my own format and the datetime come from database is not looking good

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Curently m using this

```
@Html.Label( msg[i].datetime.ToString())
```

`(4/23/2016 5:09:00 AM)` but time is shown in this format

but i want show date and time in this format`(23/4/2016 5:09 AM)`

in my chat Application and

i am saving this datetime in my database as

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.datetime, new { @Value = DateTime.Now })
```

Comment: Just use one of the [DateTime format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). And you should never set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method (you set the value of the property in the server before you send the model to the view) and using a `<label>` element is not appropriate because its not a label

Comment: So you probably want this...
@Html.Label(msg[i].datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"))

Comment: yes i want this but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
this will work if `datetime` is not nullable.

```
@Html.Label( msg[i].datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the **extension method** for label control to display required date time format.

```
public static class HelperMethods
{
     public static HtmlString MyDateTime(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, DateTime date)
     {
        return LabelExtensions.Label(htmlHelper, "LblDate", date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"));
     }
}
```

Use like below in .cshtml pages

```
@Html.MyDateTime(DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The easiest way for me is to provide the string formatter in the view. Below is the the output with the string formatter:

`23/4/2016 5:09 AM` (month with no leading zero - like you specified)

```
@Html.Label(msg[i].datetime.ToString("dd/M/yyyy h:mm tt"))
```

`23/04/2016 5:09 AM` (month with a leading zero)

```
@Html.Label(msg[i].datetime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"))
```

If you need more samples check out this page:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

@Html.Label(string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}",msg[i].datetime))

Hope it will help u ;)